# Is this a correct negation of "$111$ is a prime number"?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm taking a Methods of Proof course, and we're working on logic. One question asks for the negation of the statement "111 is a prime number." I wrote "111 is a composite number," but the answer in the solution manual was "111 is not a prime number." Is my answer still technically correct?

EDIT: I'm not sure why the number 111 showed up as 1 before, but it should be 111 and not 1. Also, to clarify, I am asking for the *negation* of the statement "111 is a prime number." I am not asking whether my response, "111 is a composite number" is a true statement (I already know that it is). I am wondering if in the study of logic, "111 is a composite number" is the correct *negation* of "111 is a prime number."

Comment: Your answer is not correct as 1 is neither prime nor composite.

Comment: His answer is correct as a true statement is the negation of a false statement.  He could have written $1+1=2$ as the negation if he wanted.

Comment: That's supposed to say 111, not 1. I'm not sure how that's showing up as 1. Also, the question is asking for the *negation* of "111 is a prime number". It is not about whether the statement "111 is a prime number" is true or false, or whether my statement "111 is composite" is true or false.

Comment: The negation of "$111$ is a prime number" is "It is not true that $111$ is a prime number" which means "$111$ is not a prime number".  Since $111$ is a positive integer and is not $1$, this implies "$111$ is a composite number" which is indeed a true statement, but the solution manual may not regard this as equivalent since the negation of "$1$ is a prime number" is not "$1$ is a composite number"

Comment: 111 is not a prime number and is not 1 == 111 is composite number

Comment: The integers are not exactly partitioned into the prime numbers and the composite numbers.  In addition, the numbers $-1$, $0$, and $1$ are not prime and are not composite, so there are numbers that are neither composite nor prime.  Consequently, the predicate "is a composite number" is not the negation of the predicate "is a prime number".

Comment: In propositional logic the negation of a statement $P$ is $\lnot P$. Thus, the negation of "$n$ is a prime number" will simply be "$n$ is **not** a prime number". Is this the same as "$n$ is a *composite* number"? No. You have to understand the difference between "negating a sentence" and "negating a predicate". The second one must be understood as the "complement" of the original predicate: thus "not-Even" is "Odd" but "not-Black" is not "White".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(x)$ be “$x$ is a prime number” and $C(x)$ be “$x$ is a composite number”.

Then $$P(111) ↔ ¬\big(¬P(111)\big)$$ and $$∀x{\in}\{2,3,\ldots\}\bigg(P(x) ↔ ¬C(x)\bigg) → \bigg(P(111) ↔ ¬C(111)\bigg)$$ are logically true, whereas $$P(111)\leftrightarrow ¬C(111).$$ is merely a contingent statement, i.e., is not **logically** true.

In other words “$111$ is composite” does not (logically) negate “$111$ is prime”, but does so under the assumption/lemma/axiom that the categories ‘composite’ and ‘prime’ are disjoint and exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

the definition of negation in the world of logic is a proposition whose assertion **specifically** denies the truth of another proposition. Your statement isn't incorrect. In logic however, you want to clearly and specifically take the proposition originally stated and take the negation of it. (e.g. A -> NOT A)